# Java AES Encryption - behind the scenes

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I have the following JAVA code for string encryption and decryption:

```
public class AES {

    private SecretKeySpec setKey(String myKey)
    {
        try {
            byte[] key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            return secretKey;
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            return null;
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    synchronized public String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secret)
    {
        try
        {
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = setKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    synchronized public String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secret) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
    {
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = setKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
    }
```

When I use my class on the string "**test**" and a secret key ("**d%D*G-JaXdRgUkXs**") for example, I get:

```
D+BhlzXKsINiKja6ZsITWQ==
```

I have tried to make the same encryption (AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding) with the same secret key in an online tool such as https://8gwifi.org/CipherFunctions.jsp,
but I get a different result:

```
Nwha9Dgv9IaN4W39C6c0cQ==
```

What I am missing?

Comment: you are using SHA-1 digest algorithm. I dont know that the secrete key that you provided is after digest or before digest. May be it can be a cause.

Comment: @flopcoder I provided the secret I send directly to the class, simply the string "d%D*G-JaXdRgUkXs".  How do I "SHA-1 digest" this key?

Comment: check answer section it may help you.

Comment: as your question description I see that you are calling setKey(secrete) method. SecretKeySpec secretKey = setKey(secret); . and setKey method contains digest method.

Comment: By using a password like the one you provided as key, you immediately reduces the security of your implementation. AES uses binary keys of 128, 196 or 256 bits .. your password have at most 100 bit's of entropy .. Putting your password through the SHA-1 don't give you those missing bit's of randomness back.

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen When you say "Password" you mean the secret key?

Comment: Yes - you use an anti-pattern often used to turn a text String (usually a "Passwords") into a binary key. You need a binary key, so why not provide a binary key, instead of deriving it from a text string. If you need to have the actual key in text form, do a simple hex encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You are using SHA-1 algorithm to generate digest and then assigning to it to **SecretKeySpec** to generate secrete key. this will give you the answer that this website gives.

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();

        System.out.println(main.encrypt("test","d%D*G-JaXdRgUkXs"));

    }
    private SecretKeySpec setKey(String myKey)
    {
        try {
            byte[] key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");

            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            return secretKey;
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    synchronized public String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secret)
    {
        try
        {
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = setKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    synchronized public String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secret) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
    {
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = setKey(secret);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
    }
}
```

If you run this code you will get below result

**Nwha9Dgv9IaN4W39C6c0cQ==**

Comment: Thanks! I don't want to change my code, I want to know how I can generate secrets for my system using online tools (what I'm missing in the proccess).

Comment: Yes but if you want to use this https://8gwifi.org/CipherFunctions.jsp and want to get same result as it gives then you have to change your code and you may remove digest .

Comment: I see, so what you are saying is that I have used some unique encryption method and I cannot use any common online tools to encrypt strings the same way?

Comment: If some online encryption method support different digest method may be then you can use online tools. but your provided online tool may be not supporting digest method to generate secrete key.

Comment: so I need to SHA-1 encode my secret key and put it there and it should work?

Comment: Yes then it will work. you just put sha-1 encoded string to setKey method and remove digest part from this method.